# Did Winston Churchill say "those who kneel for peace get humiliation and war"?

Tags: quotes, winston-churchill

Some Spanish language sites, including Facebook statuses and the Colombian National Daily [El Tiempo](http://www.eltiempo.com/archivo/documento/CMS-11836585) claim that Winston Churchill gave a quote that translates roughly as "those who kneel for peace get humiliation and war":

> "El que se arrodilla para conseguir la paz se queda con la humillación y con la guerra".
>
> Con esa frase, de Winston Churchill [...]

It is used as a political argument against peace conversations.

I couldn't find any reference that Churchill made that statement.

Comment: Similar comment that he did make, according to Wikiquote: "Britain and France had to choose between war and dishonour. They chose dishonour. They will have war."

Answer (score 6):

According to [The National Churchill Museum](http://www.nationalchurchillmuseum.org/war-quotes.html) he said

> "Those who can win a war well can rarely make a good peace, and those who could make a good peace would never have won the war."

1930, from his book *My Early Life*.

Which doesn't mean exactly the same thing but has a similar sentiment.

In [a speech in Parliament](http://www.nationalchurchillmuseum.org/neville-chamberlain-speech-1940.html) he also said, Of his predecessor Chamberlain who made the notorious Munich Agreement with Hitler and subsequently announced "peace for our time"

> Whatever else history may or may not say about these terrible, tremendous years, we can be sure that Neville Chamberlain acted with perfect sincerity according to his lights and strove to the utmost of his capacity and authority, which were powerful, to save the world from the awful, devastating struggle in which we are now engaged. This alone will stand him in good stead as far as what is called the verdict of history is concerned.

So it may be that Churchill's views on peacemakers were markedly different from what you might understand from the Spanish phrase.

Comment: I would say the *My Early Life* quote is **very** different in meaning from what is in the question.

Answer (score -2):

I also know this quote in my own language. While looking for the original one in English
I have found this link:

[Sir Winston Leonard Spencer Churchill Quotes — Military Quotes](http://www.military-quotes.com/churchill.htm)

What appears there is the following quote and an additional one said on a different occasion.

“You were given the choice between war and dishonor. You chose dishonor and you will have war.”
Churchill’s remark after Chamberlain returned from signing the Munich pact with Hitler.

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users). Is this an answer to the question? It suggests on a different occasion he made a different statement, but doesn't answer whether he said the original one.